# Borrow non-'static data in future with wasm_bindgen_futures

Tags: rust, webassembly, web-sys

I am launching multiple threads from incoming tcp connections which need to read from a file or anything that implements the `std::io::Read` and `std::io::Seek` trait.

I have the following working implementation (1):

```rust
fn upload<R: Read + Seek + Send>(file: &mut R, listen_addr: SocketAddr) -> IoResult<()> {
  let listener = TcpListener::bind(listen_addr)?;
  let file: Arc<Mutex<&mut R>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(file));

  std::thread::scope(|scope| {
    for socket in listener.incoming() {
      let socket = socket.unwrap() // error handling omitted ..
      let f = file.clone();
      scope.spawn(move || {
        start_upload_task(socket, f).unwrap();
      });
    }
  }
  Ok(())
}

fn start_upload_task<R: Read + Seek>(conn: TcpStream, file: Arc<Mutex<&mut R>>) -> IoResult<()>{
  // do something wtih file ..
  let mut buf = vec![0u8; 42];
  {
    let mut file = file.lock().unwrap();
    file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(42))?;
    file.read_exact(&mut buf)?;
  }
  Ok(())
}
```

However, since I want to use [`wasm_bindgen_futures::spawn_local`](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/wasm_bindgen_futures/fn.spawn_local.html), the future must be `'static` and there is no equivalent to `std::thread::scope` in rust webassembly that I know of.

What I end up with is the following (2):

```rust
fn upload<R: Read + Seek + Send>(file: &mut R, listen_addr: SocketAddr) -> IoResult<()> {
  let listener = TcpListener::bind(listen_addr)?;
  let file: Arc<Mutex<&mut R>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(file));

  for socket in listener.incoming() {
    let socket = socket.unwrap() // error handling omitted ..
    let f = file.clone();
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
      start_upload_task(socket, f).unwrap();
    });
  }
  Ok(())
}
```

But this gives me the following compile error:

> borrowed data escapes outside of associated function
> requirement occurs because of the type `Mutex<&mut R>`, which makes the generic argument `&mut R` invariant
> the struct `Mutex<T>` is invariant over the parameter `T`
> see https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html for more information about variance rustcE0521
> lib.rs(258, 47): `file` is a reference that is only valid in the associated function body

with the following suggestion:

```
   --> src/lib.rs:273:25
    |
258 |       fn upload<R: Read + Seek + Send>(&self, file: &mut R, listen_addr: SocketAddr) -> IoResult<()> {
    |                                                 ----  - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
    |                                                 |
    |                                                 `file` is a reference that is only valid in the associated function body
```

How do I get implementation (2) to work?

Comment: Do you control the referent of `file`? If you do, you could wrap it in `Arc<Mutex<_>>` before you pass it to `upload`.

Comment: @isaactfa I get the same error if I use `file: Arc<Mutex<&mut R>>` as argument to `upload`.

Comment: `fn upload<R: Read + Seek + Send>(file: Arc<Mutex<&'static mut R>>) -> Ioresult<()> { ... }` does compile however, but I would prefer not passing it as a `'static` reference.

Comment: Yeah, you definitely don't want a `&'static mut _` around. I mean, you should wrap whatever `R` you have. I.e. `upload` should take `Arc<Mutex<R>>` instead of `Arc<Mutex<&mut R>>`.

Comment: @isaactfa I am still getting problems with lifetime bounds: "the parameter type `R` may not live long enough".

Comment: I could add the `'static` trait with `fn upload<R: Read + Seek + Send + 'static>(...)`, but I think this is the same as using `&' static mut _` ?

Comment: It's very much not the same! Any owned value is bounded by `'static`. Whereas when you have a `&'static mut R` you'll never be able to borrow that `R` immutably ever again.

Comment: @isaactfa So the `'static` trait is the right approach here? I would then need to own the data inside the mutex. I was going for `Cursor<&[u8]>` as the `file` argument, but this means I need to change it to `Cursor<Vec<u8>>`. (`std::io::Cursor` is needed for the `Seek` trait).

Comment: Yeah, you'll most likely have to own the data down the line. I can't vouch for `Cursor<Vec<u8>>` without putting it through the borrow checker but I believe that should work. Let me know.